# Load partial view after button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have this issue, have search a lot but with now correct answer.

I have a contact form in the footer, on my _Layout page, but when I clicked the button the partial view is open in a new page.

I have remember to include the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. Here is what I have.

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Call()
    {
        return PartialView("_PartialFooter");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Call(CallMe callMe)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return PartialView("_PartialFooter");
    }
```

_Layout the scripts is above the Body tag in the bottom

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Call", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
                            {
                                <div id="result" class="margin-bottom-5">
                                    @Html.Action("Call", "Home")
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-common-small margin-bottom-10 pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
                            }

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscripts")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

}
```

_PartialFooter (the partial view)

```
@model servicemadsen.Models.CallMe


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div id="result" class="margin-bottom-5">


            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Navn" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Telefon" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CallMeMessage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Besked", @cols = 80, @rows = 7 })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, string.Empty, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, string.Empty, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CallMeMessage, string.Empty, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Hope someone could help, its probaly some dummy thing that I need

Comment: If your redirecting, it means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded correctly. Having `@section Scripts {` in a Layout makes no sense (and that part contains a 2nd copy of jquery). Move the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file to after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscripts")` (or better use the `jqueryval` bundle, and delete the `@section Scripts {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you installed the microsoft jquery unobstrusive ajax? if not try with that. i do some tests with your code and works.

EDIT : i also change some code for the tests

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Call(CallMe callMe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            callMe.CallMeMessage = callMe.CallMeMessage + " i was on the server";
        }
        return PartialView("_PartialFooter", callMe);
    }
```

and

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Call", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
        {
            <div id="result" class="margin-bottom-5">
                @Html.Action("Call", "Home")


            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-common-small margin-bottom-10 pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
            }
```

so you can see the changes.

Comment: Yes in nuget I have installed Microsofr.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax by microsoft

Comment: @tinaw25 and you add the script in the layout?

Comment: @tinaw25 this is my tests, i hope it helps you. https://github.com/Manuel-Iriarte/stackoverflow-20161207

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You are my true hero :-). It is working now, I just copy some of your code in mine

Comment: glad to help!! ;)